# How to get values added in subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to get the value of subviews which added to UIView.

I Have added five button to the subviews.

Now i need to get 2nd 3rd 4th from the subviews.

```
for(id btn in [myview subviews]){

.... which prints all the elements added in view.
}
```

how to get specific elements added to subviews.

@thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either store pointers to the buttons when you create them, or assign unique tag values to each button and fetch the buttons by their tags.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, `[[myview subviews] objectAtIndex:2]`.

It’s safe*ish* to rely on the order of items in subviews. Though they can be rearranged as side effects of other operations. You’d be better off using data members or assigning a `tag`.

Comment: Either it's safe or it's not, and relying on the order of subviews in a view is not safe.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that everything in programming is black or white :P. Though I agree, I wouldn’t do this. But this was the answer to his question. Your answer is making assumptions about what he wants.

Comment: It's safe to rely on the order of subviews in your own view classes (if they directly subclass UIView) in the sense that iOS won't change the order under your feet. It's not a good idea to, but neither is another class adding subviews to your view hierarchy.